# Unable to import issues

Tags: python, import, importerror

I am getting multiple errors when trying to run [this](https://github.com/SamPom100/UnusualVolumeDetector) program. Here they are below:

Unable to import 'matplotlib.pyplot'

Unable to import 'yfinance'

Unable to import 'dateutil.relativedelta'

Unable to import 'pandas'

Unable to import 'mplcursors'

Unable to import 'matplotlib'

Unable to import 'matplotlib.dates'

Unable to import 'dateutil'

Unable to import 'numpy'

I have never used python before so I am really confused as to what to do?

EDIT: SOLVED

I had to change the path and install python in addition to Visual Studio and restart the whole thing. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You should probably follow a tutorial before running a random piece of code you found online. Specifically for this issue, you should learn about pip.

Comment: I just realized checking the link, there is a whole section called "how to run this" that deals with the issue your experiencing. Did you even read the link you posted?

Answer (score 0):

If you have python installed, then the most immediate way to get this working is to do:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, I strongly recommend using a virtual environment for every new project you look at. There are many different ways to make a virtual environment so I leave it to you to research that.